# Update Field in Many to Many relation with Sequelize on NodeJs, with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i have a relation Many to Many to do relation between Tournaments and Payers. So i have 3 models :

- Player : with player_id
- Tournament: with tournament_id
- Participant (relation's table) witch join player_id, tournament_id, and contain un other field 'Status' to define if the player's participation to a tournament is 'accepted' or 'refused'.

My question is : how to do to update this field 'status' ?

I tried this, but is wrong !!!

```
const participation = await Participant.findAll({
        where: {
          user_id: userId,
          tournament_id: tournamentId,
        },
      });

await participation.update({ state: 'accepted' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the reason. But I assume that you shouldn't use the findAll method for your purpose.

findAll returns instance array, but update method belongs the model instance.

There are some possible solutions, I guess.

1. Using Participant.findOne method and update it.

`const participation = await Participant.findOne({ where: { user_id: userId, tournament_id: tournamentId });`

2. Using Participant.findAll method and loop the result array for update.

`participation.map((p) => p.update({ state: 'accepted' });`

3. Using update method with where condition directly.

`await Participant.update({ state: 'accepted' }, { where: { user_id: userId, tournament_id: tournamentId };`

Comment: Nice "bonbon42" ! using "findOne" and it works !
Congratulations !!!!!